# Array fields in Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I would like to use nova text field to save array and then JSON into database.

For example

```
<input name="order[name]" type="text"> 
<input name="order[email]" type="text">
```

Please suggest a better way to achieve this using NOVA.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of Nova v2.0.6, there's no way to force specific keys for the JSON on a `KeyValue` or `Code` field.

However, you can use the [64robots/nova-fields](https://github.com/64robots/nova-fields) package which supports for a JSON field:

```
use R64\NovaFields\JSON;

JSON::make('Order', [
    Text::make('Name'),
    Email::make('Email'),
], 'order'),
```

For more information: https://github.com/64robots/nova-fields/blob/master/docs/json.md

Comment: Hello, I can't define keys using this method. What if there are set of keys that need to filled?

Comment: @seoppc what do you mean? You absolutely define the keys using the example provided above.